# Having problems with the Festival Dance mini-game

Tags: kingdom-hearts-3

I am having problems with the Festival Dance mini-game, Repunzel never arm bumps with me and the combo disappears. How can I fix this? I even get the circle part just fine. The final sequence just does not activate.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to get the high score is to press the triangle button at the end of the haywheel to get the big finish. When you have the big finish make sure you don't break your chain. 
I struggled with this too and I figured out I was pressing the square button at the wrong time when trying to clap with my current partner. This was breaking my chaing and I couldn't get the 70,000 points. 
When I slowed down a little and got my chain as high as I could, that's when I got my 70,000 points.

Comment: While this is good info, the question isn’t asking how to achieve the high score for the trophy